# Delete row from table that is NULL and has the same DATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL question, which I am not able to handle.

I need to delete rows from a table, which are NULL in the date_to columns, but have a different value to the date_from column.

[image: table]

The column I want to delete is the one with the number 3.

It has the same value in date_from and is null.

This was my own approach:

```
select
    date_from, id, count(*) number_of_rows_with_the_same_datefrom
from 
    test
group by 
    date_from, id
having 
    count(*) > 1
```

This returns all the rows that have the same from date with the same ID, from there I was lost:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use a CTE and Row_Number()

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By ID, date_from Order by date_to Desc)
     From  YourTable
)
Select *        --<< Remove if Satisfied
--Delete        --<< Remove comment if Statisfied
 From cte
 Where RN>1 and date_to is null
```

Returns  (Records to be deleted)

```
ID  name    date_from   date_to RN
2   Jim     2012-08-01  NULL    2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked flawlesly. I used 1 hour and was completely lost. It seemed so simple, but turned out to be difficult.

Comment: @uba2012 As you know, delete should be approached with extreme caution, I've made HUGE mistakes.  CTE or Common Table Expression can be very useful.  Also you should get comfortable with the Window functions / OVER clause. Just run the select within the CTE to see better visualize what Row_Number() is doing.

Comment: @Peter Cappelletti I have made a test table from the real data to test on:) so no problem there. I need to understand how this works. If you see what i have added to my first post, it shows what i tried. I first tried to find rows that have the same date_from under a having count(*)>1. So in this way i knew that every group would have one that satisfies the condition where date_to is null and date_from is the same

Comment: @uba2012 Your updated query will identify the records which have the same id,date_from not necessarily a null date_to.  Seriously run >>> Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By ID, date_from Order by date_to Desc) From Test <<< and watch the pattern of Row_Number()

Comment: Just did it, it works. Im going to read about window functions. They seem very usefull.. If i was not to use window function, but rather ctes and set operators. How would the query look like then?. Iam trying to learn by studiying multiple ways of doing the same things. anyways thanks for your help

Comment: @uba2012 The discovery is the fun part, and I applaud your efforts on learning multiple ways of doing things.  That alone make you a better developer.

Answer (score 0):

Using an exists statement, this seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

```
DELETE FROM table A
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM table B 
              WHERE A.Id = B.ID 
                and A.Date_from = B.date_from 
                and A.Name = B.Name
                and B.Date_To is null)
```

Assuming ID and Name and date_from make some sort of key...  I'd be more comfortable knowing what the PK is on this table. (or a unique index if one exists)

To verify it's going to do what you want; run this first.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table A
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM table B 
              WHERE A.Id = B.ID 
                and A.Date_from = B.date_from 
                and A.Name = B.Name
                and B.Date_To is null)
```

Comment: Hi i ran the select statement, but it doesnt work. It finds 2 rows. And there is no key in the table

Comment: Hi xQbert it the type=Date

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure then.  I can't see why this would work. unless names have spaces in them or ID's have spaces in them...  (which is why I was concerned about a Unique index)  and why generating a rownumber as a unique key may be the best approach.